# wordpress $wpdb get result method not return results

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i have one new table in wordpress which contains 100000 rows.i want retrieve all rows.

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM newtable";

$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

When i execute this query is return nothing.
but

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM newtable limit 0,25000";

$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

then it return 25k rows i don't understand what is problem with 100000 rows.

i want all 100000 rows.i have try many but don't find any valid solution.

Any Kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: I assume you've tried `LIMIT 0,100000`?

Comment: yes i have tried this one still get result null.

Comment: Have you tried specifying an output_type? See - http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: i have changed output value but still return null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check --

- PHP Memory Limit
- Query Execution Time
- PHP Script execution time in this case

Try by increasing this server settings and let me know then

Comment: i have increased memory limit by this method http://www.dailyblogging.org/wordpress/increase-wordpress-memory-limit/ and also change value of PHP script exection time to 0 still return null value and it also stop futher exection of script running and dosen't  error message.

Comment: @JaykeshPatel instead of SELECT * try SELECT col_name and check if its working or not ..also run this query if you are using phpmyadmin and check the execution time for it